# Is there an equivalent to DBus on OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, dbus

Is there an equivalent to Linux DBus on OSX?  I mean, is there a "message bus" available by default on OSX?

**Disclaimer:** OSX newbie here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the closest analog would be distributed notifications (or notifications for same-process communication). It's not a perfect analog, but it fits into roughly the same niche. You can read more about it in Apple's [Notification Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html), particularly the part about the [distributed notification center](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html).

Comment: +1: this functionality gets me at least closer to where I want to be headed. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

If you need to use DBus you can install it via [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).
Homebrew is a package manager for OS X providing a lot of libraries which where mostly written with Linux as their primary target.
The DBus package can be found [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/d-bus.rb)

However, this is not installed by default and if you intend to write Cocoa applications the way to go would be to use the (distributed) notification center as mipadi explained in [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723936/is-there-an-equivalent-to-dbus-on-osx/2724092#2724092) (which you also accepted).

If you need a robust middleware for communication you can also have a look at [IceTouch](http://zeroc.com/icetouch/index.html) from [ZeroC](http://zeroc.com/index.html) which is a Cocoa library for using the services and functionality offered by their Ice framework.
The package contains [IceStorm](http://zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.4.1-IceTouch/manual/IceStorm.html#22064) for example which is a publish/subscribe server or the [IceGrid](http://zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.4.1-IceTouch/manual/IceGrid.html#22064) service which can be used to build large scale distributed systems

Answer (score 4):

There's Mach's **ports**, which will probably do what you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_(kernel) .

Comment: hmmm... from a quick browse, it appears that "Mach Port" is really just an IPC without the higher level semantics of publish/subscribe... or am I mistaking?

Comment: @jldupont: yes, Mach ports are just queues and are the lowest level of IPC in Mac OS X - there are various other IPC mechanisms built on top of these.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. +1 for pointing me in the Mach Port direction... didn't know about those.

Comment: @jldupont: you might want to look at things like `Mach messaging`, `kqueue` and `notify`, depending on what kind of level you want to do IPC at. Get Amit Singh's book if you're serious about this kind of stuff.

Answer (score -3):

You could check [DarwinPorts](http://darwinports.com/). It should include the dBus libraries.

Comment: MacPorts is the correct source for this: http://www.macports.org/ There is a long and contentious history between the real MacPorts project and the DarwinPorts scraper.