# Python Error: Failed building wheels while importing dbus

Tags: python, dbus

I'm using PyCharm on Mac.

I was running a module with notify2 in it and got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus' as an error.

After trying to pip3 install dbus (and dbus-python), and sudo, I get ERROR: Failed building wheel for dbus-python.

Only brew installing dbus worked, but my PyCharm cannot access it still.

I tried almost all of the related threads here, but nothing worked.
I am relatively new to Python as well, so if someone had an advice about what else could I try, I would really appreciate a beginner-friendly response.

Thank you!

Comment: D-Bus is primarily a Linux thing. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723936/7721752

Comment: Thanks for the link! But then why PyCharm is asking for it when I try to run notify2?

Comment: If brew install worked, maybe when you create the Virtual Environment in Pycharm, you just need click the box for "Inherit global site-packages` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: thank you! I will try that :)